# How to add WYSIWYG to a custom category field

Tags: magento, wysiwyg, backend

after 4 hours I need some help.
Working on Magento 1.9

I added a Custom Category Attribute with success, and I can see the field in MySql db `add_category_attribute` growingUp after every upgrade of version, I can see the content in frontend template too.

Here the code of config and php

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <SMN_CustomCategoryAttribute>
            <version>0.0.3</version>
        </SMN_CustomCategoryAttribute>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <resources>
            <add_category_attribute>
                <setup>
                    <module>SMN_CustomCategoryAttribute</module>
                    <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </add_category_attribute>
            <add_category_attribute_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </add_category_attribute_write>
            <add_category_attribute_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </add_category_attribute_read>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

here the php:

```
 <?php
     $this->startSetup();
     $this->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'custom_attribute', array(
         'group'         => 'General',
         'input'         => 'textarea',
         'type'          => 'text',
         'label'         => 'Custom attribute',
         'backend'       => '',
         'visible'       => true,
         'required'      => false,
        'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
     ));

     $this->endSetup();
```

Now i would to add the WYSIWYG button on the field added.
I change the version in my config.xml
I rename the php file from `mysql4-install-0.0.1.php` to `mysql4-upgrade-0.0.1-0.0.2.php` 
I change the code adding:

```
     'wysiwyg_enabled' => true,
     'visible_on_front' => true,
     'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
```

I added:

```
$installer->updateAttribute('catalog_category', 'custom_attribute', 'is_wysiwyg_enabled', 1);
$installer->updateAttribute('catalog_category', 'custom_attribute', 'is_html_allowed_on_front', 1);
```

I flush caches and indexing, but nothing.

It's very simple code I don't know what I can do again.

Comment: You have defined global scope, are you sure you're looking at global scope in the back-end?

Comment: Thanks for the answers.
The first change is showing, the field appears, and in Front-end template the values are filled (Obviously in plain text, not formatted)

I will try to change the query with a SCOPE WEBSITE or STORE.
I will let you know.